# Hide the CSV Export option from the selected reports in SSRS

Tags: csv, ssrs-2008-r2

I want to hide the CSV Export option from the selected reports in SSRS. I do not want it for all the reports but only for few reports. I want to do it through SSRS only and not through Report view controller. Is it possible?

**Note** : There are solutions which will disable the option globally.But I want it for specific reports only. I don't have access to the dot net project so I can not use the pre_render event. Can I make this happen only using SSRS ? Please consider this before marking it as a duplicate

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SSRS - Disabling export options (eg. PDF) for individual reports](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15831328/ssrs-disabling-export-options-eg-pdf-for-individual-reports)

Comment: @BIDeveloper :The solution will disable the options globally. I dont have access to the dot net project so I can not use the pre_render event. Can I make this happen only using SSRS ? That is my question.