# Reporting Services (Portal) Hide Download Menu

Tags: reporting-services

Do anyone know a way to hide the download menu for users in Microsoft Reporting Services?

[Picture of the menu i mean](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nGINA.png)

Wo don´t want our users to use this software (Not everyone). This would be a convenience feature. If you need further information feel free to ask :)

Comment: Possible solutions here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15831328/ssrs-disabling-export-options-eg-pdf-for-individual-reports

Comment: Hi, I dont think this will work. In the mentioned post they are talking about the export functionality. I am talking about the download item where you can download the "Report Designer" and "Power BI" and so one.

Yes this was maybe my fault download and export seems to be the same :)

Comment: If the user just has Browser permissions, I don't think they will see that download feature. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: I have explicitly set the permission to browser for all users (expect the admins) but the download link is still there (I have also tried to force refresh and restart the browser just to be sure).

Comment: Stupid question... are you an admin and are you displaying the portal with your credentials?

Comment: yes and yes/no :) 
I use two browser sessions. One as admin (Internet Explorer) and one as user (Firefox [no SSO]) to test the changes as different user. When I write I see the link then I mean I see the link as user.

Answer (score 0):

Log to your SSRS Database and lookup the `ShowDownloadMenu` parameter in the `ConfigurationInfo` Table, it'll show you that the parameter is "true", just set it false.

For that you just use the following query:

```sql
select ConfigInfoID, Name, Value from configurationinfo where name = 'ShowDownloadMenu'
```

For that you use:

```sql
update [configurationinfo] set [value] = 'false' where configinfoid = 'Replace with ConfigInfoID Hash from the ShowDownloadMenu Parameter from the previous query'
```

This will help you disable the Download Button.

[image]