# reportviewer hide exporting to word and excel options

Tags: c#, asp.net, reportviewer

i am using visual studio 2012 and I have a rdlc report. I want to hide word and excel in the export option in ssrs ReportViewer. I Have tried couple of things but nothing seems to work! if any body can help i'd be so grateful :)

Thanks

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1499885/reportviewer-hide-pdf-export?

Answer (score 1):

Simple Jquery trick to hide Word and Excel options from RDLC Report Viewer:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $("a[title='Excel']").parent().hide(); // Remove Excel from export dropdown.
 $("a[title='Word']").parent().hide(); // Remove Word from export dropdown.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a snippet from one of my projects (VB, but you can easily translate):

```
              With rv
                .Reset()
                .Visible = True

                .ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Remote
                .ServerReport.ReportServerUrl = New Uri(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("ReportServer"))
                .ServerReport.ReportPath = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("ReportPath") & ssrsReportName
                .ServerReport.ReportServerCredentials = CType(New IDOI.HealthRateReview.Common.ReportServerCredentials(), Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.IReportServerCredentials)
                .ServerReport.Refresh()
                Dim wantedExportFormats As New List(Of String)
                ' Any formats not explicitly enabled are disabled.
                wantedExportFormats.Add("PDF")
                wantedExportFormats.Add("CSV")
                wantedExportFormats.Add("WORD")
                'wantedExportFormats.Add("XML")
                'wantedExportFormats.Add("EXCEL")
                'wantedExportFormats.Add("MHTML")
                'wantedExportFormats.Add("IMAGE")
                'wantedExportFormats.Add("HTML4.0")
                'wantedExportFormats.Add("RGDI")
                'wantedExportFormats.Add("RPL")
                'wantedExportFormats.Add("XLTemplate")
                'wantedExportFormats.Add("WordTemplate")
                'wantedExportFormats.Add("NULL")
                EnableWantedExportFormats(rv.ServerReport, wantedExportFormats)
                '.ServerReport.ListRenderingExtensions()
                .AsyncRendering = True
            End With
```

Comment: I haven't used vb ever. any help on what to change?@Duston

Comment: rv is the ReportViewer object.  Just add rv before all the . references (for example rv.Reset(), add ; at the ends of the lines and change the variable declarations.  Aside from that, use Google to figure out what the VB is doing and do the same in C#.

Answer (score 0):

All solutions I tried did not work for me (trying to modify the m_isVisible boolean property of the RenderingExtension for example).  However, the simple jquery below did work for me and is much easier to implement.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("a[title='PDF']").parent().hide();  // Remove from export dropdown.
    $("a[title='MHTML (web archive)']").parent().hide();  
    $("a[title='TIFF file']").parent().hide();  
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add below code in PreRender event of your RDLC Report Viewer control

```
protected void ReportViewer1_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (RenderingExtension extension in ReportViewer1.LocalReport.ListRenderingExtensions())
    {
        if(extension.Name.ToUpper()=="WORDOPENXML" || extension.Name.ToUpper()=="EXCEL" || extension.Name.ToUpper()=="WORD" ||extension.Name.ToUpper()=="EXCELOPENXML" )
        {
            FieldInfo fi = extension.GetType().GetField("m_isVisible",BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
            fi.SetValue(extension, false);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This code was the only that worked for me. Im using a web page in asp net 4.0. I let this comment for reference, the code in at least other 10 sites didn't work for me.

```
protected void ReportViewer1_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (RenderingExtension extension in ReportViewer1.LocalReport.ListRenderingExtensions())
    {
        if (extension.Name.ToUpper() == "WORDOPENXML" || extension.Name.ToUpper() == "EXCEL" || extension.Name.ToUpper() == "WORD" || extension.Name.ToUpper() == "EXCELOPENXML")
        {
            FieldInfo fi = extension.GetType().GetField("m_isVisible", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
            fi.SetValue(extension, false);
        }
    }
}
```